# Unit Test button added to view

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am a unit test newbie, I am testing if my button has been added to the view.

My first test passes correctly:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(vc.button, "button Not Initialised")
```

But my second test fails when i have the view.addSubview(button) in the code

```
XCTAssertNotNil(vc.button.superview, "button Not added to view")
```

My question is how do i test to see if the button has been added to the view, I am not using storyboards, everything is coded. Because the first test will pass regardless of if i have addSubview in the code or not.

Thanks

In my ViewController class i initialise the button:

```
 private(set) lazy var myButton: UIButton = {
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
    return myButton
}()
```

and in viewDidLoad i add it to subview and give it constraints:

```
view.addSubview(myButton)
```

My test function is:

```
func testAddRoomButtonInRoomsViewController() {
    let vc = myViewController()
    XCTAssertNotNil(vc.myButton, "Button Not Initialised")
    XCTAssertNotNil(vc.myButton.superview, "Button Not Added To View")
}
```

Comment: Could you post a full code sample please?

Comment: Yes could you share the actual code you want to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewDidLoad` is not called in your test case, therefore it fails. You have to call it manually.

**1. Introduce an extension**

```
    extension UIViewController {

        func startViewLifecycle() {
            view.setNeedsLayout()
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

**2. Call it in your test case:**

```
func testAddRoomButtonInRoomsViewController() {
    let vc = myViewController()
    vc.startViewLifecycle()

    XCTAssertNotNil(vc.myButton, "Button Not Initialised")
    XCTAssertNotNil(vc.myButton.superview, "Button Not Added To View")
}
```

Comment: The recommended way to call viewDidLoad() from a test should be like this:

let sut = ViewController()
sut.loadViewIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely valid to write a test to check if a view has been added to a superview. I have just tried the following and it passes successfully:

```
- (void)testView
{
    UIView *superview = [UIView new];
    UIView *view = [UIView new];

    [superview addSubview:view];
    XCTAssertNotNil(view.superview);
}
```

If your assertion `XCTAssertNotNil(vc.button.superview, "button Not added to view")`fails it is either because you don't add the subview to the superview (which is likely what you want to test) or because your superview gets deallocated before you can complete your test.

If the latter you need to make sure that you keep a strong reference to the superview to perform your test - a superview keeps a strong reference to each of its subviews but not the other way round (as that would generate a retained cycle). So `view.superview` is really a weak property and it would be set to `nil` if/when the superview is deallocated.

```
- (void)testView
{
    UIView *superview = [UIView new];
    UIView *view = [UIView new];

    [superview addSubview:view];

    superview = nil;

    XCTAssertNil(view.superview);//superview will be deallocated by now - this value is nil
}
```

I hope this helps.

//UPDATE:

Looking at the code it is now clear that you were not calling `addSubview:` before the test as the `viewDidLoad` was not called. @figs suggested how to work around this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, I have added more code to the original question as I am still slightly confused as to what i am doing wrong :S